# Is it possible to declare / export a static function in C++/CLI?

Tags: function, static, c++-cli

For example I wanted to do the following:

```
namespace Test
{
    static bool PerformTest()
    {
        bool result = false;

        // Todo: do something

        return result;
    }
}
```

..and then call that function from another module:

```
Test::PerformTest();
```

..I get an error saying that PerformTest is not part of the namespace. If it were a class I'd put this down to a missing 'public' statement but as far as I can tell you can only make ref classes and structs public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static bool PerformTest()
```

The *static* keyword means different things in different contexts.  Here it means "no external linkage" which it the exact opposite you want.  You'll have to remove it.

It isn't clear whether or not /clr is in effect when this code gets compiled.  Let's assume it is.  The CLR has no support for free functions like this, it only supports class methods.  The C++/CLI compiler deals with this by creating a dummy class named `<Module>` in the global namespace, making a free function a method of that class that is static and has *internal* accessibility.  Both the class name and the accessibility specifier keeps it well out of reach from a C# program.  Reflection should work but I've never tried it.

There is one back-door, you can export a free function just like you can in a native DLL project.  Same syntax:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
bool __stdcall PerformTest() { 
    // etc.. 
}
```

The C++/CLI compiler exports a stub with the same name as the function that any native code can call.  The stub loads the CLR, if required, switches to managed code execution and calls the actual PerformTest() function.  Any C# code can now pinvoke the function.  The overhead is a bit silly but that should not matter much in a test scenario.

Comment: Actually, my function naming was a little misleading; this actually came about where I had a helper function to delete the contents of a generic list. The GC wasn't collecting fast enough so we needed something to kill things off quicker. With that in mind, my original solution (the same one parapula suggested) is probably the neatest option. Once again though, I owe you a beer for the background and increased understanding!

Comment: *"The CLR has no support for free functions"*: I was under the impression that the CLR supports free functions, but languages built on top of it like C# do not. Is the key to this in the *"like this"*?

Comment: It is the other way around.  Free functions in C++/CLI and VB.NET are emulated by making them static methods of a hidden class.  C# makes it explicit with the `static class` keywords.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't allow static functions at namespace level you have to put them in a class

**C# code**

```
namespace CLITest
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static bool PerformTest()
        {
            bool result = false;

            // Todo: do something

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**C++/CLI code**

```
using namespace CLITest;

int main()
{

    Test::PerformTest();
    return 0;
}
```

will do what you want

Comment: That was the point I was getting at; is there any way to export functions without wrapping them in a static class or struct..

Comment: @JonCage Is `PerformTest` a C# or C++ function ?